# Lilypond: Collisions with ledger lines - Can the length of an individual ledger line be modified?

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I'm trying to replicate the elegance of the shortening of a ledger line to avoid a collision with a stem as seen in the following picture:

[image: Ledger line shortening]

Ledger lines don't seem to avoid collisions as you can see in this example:

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "english"


\new Staff { 
  \clef bass
  <<
    \new Voice {
      \voiceOne
      ds16 fs b fs
    }
  
    \new Voice {
      \voiceTwo
      \once \override NoteColumn.force-hshift = #0.25 b,,8 r 
    }
  
    \new Voice {
      \voiceThree \stemDown
      \once \override NoteColumn.force-hshift = #0 ds4
    }
  >>
}
```

[image: Ledger line collision]

*Note: I forced a horizontal shift on two of the note columns to obtain a result similar to the published edition:*
*1. So that the noteheads of the notes in unison are merged*
*2. So that the lowest voice (\voiceTwo) is slightly shifted to the right at that same musical moment.*

I think that giving the stem a white padding isn't optimal because the ledger lines have rounded ends and this solution would give the ledger line a square end.

So, is there a way to shorten a particular ledger line? Or what other solution would you suggest?

Comment: You should file a bug for lilypond, as this is a deviation from their goal of achieving the same quality as hand engraved scores.

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't think `whiteout` would be the best solution, but since there's a lack of other options I thought I'd share:

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "english"

\score {
  \new Staff { 
    \clef bass
    <<
      \new Voice {
        \voiceOne
        ds16 fs b fs
      }
      
      \new Voice {
        \voiceTwo
        \once \override NoteColumn.force-hshift = #0.25 
        b,,8 r 
      }
  
      \new Voice {
        \voiceThree \stemDown
        \once \override Stem.whiteout = #2
        \once \override NoteColumn.force-hshift = #0 ds4
      }
    >>
  }
  \layout {
    \context {
      \Score
        \override Stem.layer = #-1
        \override LedgerLineSpanner.layer = #-2
    }
  }
}
```

In the score `context`, I put the note stems on a lower layer than the rest of the score and I put the ledger lines one layer below the stem. This way, any `whiteout` on the stem covers up the ledger line but none of the rest of the score.

With `\once \override Stem.whiteout = #2`, I simply determine the thickness of the `whiteout` on the stem.

[image]

In the above code and image, I've kept the `force-hshift` of the low B, but you can remove that override and increase the whiteout on the D♯ (3.5 worked for me) if you prefer:

[image]

Comment: This may be the best solution, but the first thing that I noticed was the lack of curvature on the left end of the ledger line, even before I'd seen that this was the specific concern raised in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This would require to change `ledger-line-spanner.cc:Ledger_line_spanner::print` to allow for different extents for different Ledger Lines. Lilypond does something like this with Accidentals, but that is in fact easier than trying to handle Stems from different Voices. So I’d suggest to change this function to take for example
`LedgerLineSpanner.details.[staff-position].[...]` to override some details for LLs at [staff-position].

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this is way above my level. I might unfortunately have to stick to whiteout padding for now if no other solutions arise.

Comment: @PedroTecla Yes, that’s a bit what I’m saying. As this is part of the C++-functionalilty it is a bit hard to change this, and there is not yet a mechanism to achieve this.